# jQuery: Convert Attribute Values to Nested Array (Strings to Numbers)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Using jQuery, I would like to get each attribute value, insert it into an array and then insert each array into an array.

From this HTML:

```
   <ul>
        <li data-bbox="-121,20,-36,30">Item 1</li>
        <li data-bbox="-122,30,-46,40">Item 2</li>
        <li data-bbox="-123,40,-56,50">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
```

I'm trying to create this type of nested array:

```
var bboxArray = [
    [-121,20,-36,30],
    [-122,30,-46,40],
    [-123,40,-56,50]
];
```

...and convert the strings to numbers.

I'm assuming I need to do something like this:

```
var bboxArray = [];
$('li[data-bbox]').each(function() {
  bboxArray.push($(this).attr('data-bbox').split(','));
});
```

Comment: I just tried your code on CodePen. It is working fine. http://codepen.io/tekesteg/pen/MyXEQW?editors=1111. Check out the console out put.

Comment: yes working https://jsfiddle.net/shoesq65/

Comment: not working, those are strings, he is asking for numbers...( I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/bemilu/1/edit?html,js,console)

While your code does work, it is returning strings instead of the numbers you have in your required output this will do that:

I simply added `.map(Number)` at the end of your `push`

```
$('li[data-bbox]').each(function() {
  bboxArray.push($(this).attr('data-bbox').split(',').map(Number));
});
```

Comment: Yep. Sorry. I didn't make that more clear. I also wanted to convert from string to numbers. Thanks!

Comment: youre welcome! can you edit the title in case anyone else see it? Thanks!

Comment: I edited the title and the post to make it more clear. If you would like to suggest something additional, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.map()` method like so:

```
var bboxArray = $('ul > li').map(function() {
    return [ $(this).data('bbox').split(',') ];
}).get();
```

```js
var bboxArray = $('ul > li').map(function() {
    return [ $(this).data('bbox').split(',') ];
}).get();
console.log( bboxArray );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <ul>
        <li data-bbox="-121,20,-36,30">Item 1</li>
        <li data-bbox="-122,30,-46,40">Item 2</li>
        <li data-bbox="-123,40,-56,50">Item 3</li>
    </ul>
```